# django form feeding from models' instances

Tags: python, django, forms, web

After spending nearly 20 hours of research I think its time to ask here!

Before all, I am very new to Django!

I made a model class which later will have instances. These instances would be the choices for another model class' instance's attribute

> class People:  Tom, Peter, Ben
>
> class Myself:
> name: "/text_entry input/ "
> best friend: `"/scroll down/radio type input"/ of class People instances`

My wording probably isn't precise enough, but I hope the question gets across

Answer (score 0):

You might be talking about foreign keys/ relationships.

You would be using the `ModelChoiceField` in your form.

You can read about the forms fields [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField)

And further reference for model forms in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/)